# Android WebView After Clicking the Image it's not setting the image on the screen?

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, android-webview, android-camera

Here is my code where i am trying to render my app in android webview. I am facing issue, where i want to click the picture using my android camera and set it on the screen. I am able to click the image but it's not setting the image on my screen.

Any help is appreciated?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);
  const [capturedImageData, setCapturedImageData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if running in Android WebView
    const isWebView = window.Android && typeof window.Android.openCamera === "function";

    if (!isWebView) {
      // If not running in Android WebView, access the user's camera using the WebRTC API
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error accessing the camera:", error);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  // Callback function to set the captured image on the screen
  window.setImageCallback = (imageData) => {
    if (imageData && imageRef.current) {
      imageRef.current.src = `data:image/jpeg;base64, ${imageData}`;
      setCapturedImageData(imageData);
    }
  };

  // Handle opening the camera
  const openCamera = () => {
    if (window.Android && typeof window.Android.openCamera === "function") {
      // If running in Android WebView, call the openCamera function
      window.Android.openCamera();
    } else {
      console.log("Open camera functionality is not available.");
    }
  };

  // Handle capturing an image
  const captureImage = () => {
    if (window.Android && typeof window.Android.captureImage === "function") {
      // If running in Android WebView, call the captureImage function
      window.Android.captureImage();
    } else {
      console.log("Capture image functionality is not available.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay playsInline />

      {capturedImageData ? (
        // Display the captured image
        <div>
          <img ref={imageRef} alt="Captured" src={`data:image/jpeg;base64, ${capturedImageData}`} />
          <button onClick={() => setCapturedImageData(null)}>Clear Image</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        // Show an "Open Camera" button to open the camera
        <button onClick={openCamera}>Capture Image</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WebcamCapture;
```

```
mport android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    private WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        MyJavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true) ;
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); // Enable geolocation

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
//            @Override
//            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
//                //L.d("onPermissionRequest");
//                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
//                    request.grant(request.getResources());
//                }
//            }
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // Show a dialog asking the user for permission
                showGeolocationPermissionDialog(origin, callback);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                String message = "YourAppTag" +  cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId();
               // Log.d("YourAppTag", cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId() );
                System.out.println(message);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // This line ensures that the WebView will handle the URL instead of launching it in an external browser.
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true; // Return true to indicate that we've handled the URL loading.
            }

            // You can also handle other WebViewClient methods here if needed.
        });

        // Check and request camera permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        } else {
            // Permission already granted
            loadWebView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Camera permission granted
                loadWebView();
            } else {
                // Camera permission denied
                // Handle the denial as needed
            }
        }
    }

    private void showGeolocationPermissionDialog(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Show a dialog asking the user for permission
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Geolocation Permission")
                .setMessage("Allow this app to access your location?")
                .setPositiveButton("Allow", (dialog, which) -> {
                    // The user granted permission
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Deny", (dialog, which) -> {
                    // The user denied permission
                    callback.invoke(origin, false, false);
                })
                .show();
    }

    private void loadWebView() {
        webView.loadUrl("https://test.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // The camera activity was successful, and you can handle the captured image here.
                // The captured image might be available in the 'data' Intent.
                // For example, you can display the captured image in an ImageView.
                // Example:
                // Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                // imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the camera action.
                // Handle this case as needed.
            } else {
                // The camera action failed for some reason.
                // Handle this case as needed.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    private Context context;
    private ImageCaptureCallback imageCaptureCallback;

    public MyJavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setImageCaptureCallback(ImageCaptureCallback callback) {
        this.imageCaptureCallback = callback;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void openCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } else {
            showToast("No camera app available on this device.");
        }
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onImageCaptured(Uri imageUri) {
        if (imageCaptureCallback != null) {
            try {
                InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                String base64Image = encodeImageToBase64(selectedImage);

                imageCaptureCallback.onCapture(base64Image);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("Error reading the captured image.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private String encodeImageToBase64(Bitmap image) {
        if (image != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public interface ImageCaptureCallback {
        void onCapture(String imageData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the method ```setCapturedImageData(null)``` with null? Also, are you sure the path you give is correct?

Comment: @tomerpacific   window.setImageCallback = (imageData) => {
    if (imageData && imageRef.current) {
      imageRef.current.src = `data:image/jpeg;base64, ${imageData}`;
      setCapturedImageData(imageData);
    }
  };